# how to create a vector such that each box is the head of a chain list?

Tags: c++, vector

My question is: What I can do instead of following?.
I want to create a vector such that each box is the head of a chain list, 'insert_beg' is a function that insert the elements (x) in the beginning of the list.i have to initialize every box created by NULL.

```
struct list
{
    int info;
    list* suivant;
};

void insert_beg(list* &debut,int x){
list* nouveau;
nouveau = new list;
nouveau->info = x;
nouveau->suivant = debut;
debut = nouveau;
}

int main()
{
    int n=5;
    vector<list*> tab;

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       x=n*2;
       tab.puch_back(?);
       insert_beg(tab[i],x);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<std::list<int>>`? Assuming you indeed need the node based container.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly then you need something like the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct list
{
    int info;
    list* suivant;
};

void insert_beg( list * &head, int info )
{
    head = new list { info, head };
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 5;
    std::vector<list *> tab;
    tab.reserve( N );

    std::fill_n( std::back_inserter( tab ), N, nullptr ); 

    std::for_each( tab.begin(), tab.end(), 
        [=]( list * &head ){ insert_beg( head, 2 * N ); } );

    std::for_each( tab.begin(), tab.end(),
        []( const list * head ) { std::cout << head->info << ' '; } );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 10 10 10 10
```

That is initially all pointers to list in the vector shall be initialized by `nullptr`.

You can do it simply by calling the standard algorithm `std::fill_n`

```
std::fill_n( std::back_inserter( tab ), N, nullptr );
```

If your compiler does not support the literal `nullptr` then you can rewrite the above call the following way

```
std::fill_n( std::back_inserter( tab ), N, ( list * )0 );
```

Comment: look at the 'insert_beg' function

Answer (score 0):

If you want insert_beg to do all the initialization work of the list, you can just(make sure insert_beg handles the nullptr case)

```
tab.push_back(nullptr);
```

tab is a std::vector of list*, so you can also push back a list*

```
tab.push_back(new list);
```

You can then use operator[] to access the head and modify the head's info and suivant:

```
tab[i]->info  = x;
tab[i]->suivant = nullptr;
```

You can also have a constructor for the list class to do the above in one line.

```
list(int x = 0, list* next = nullptr) : info(x), suivant(next) {}

tab.push_back(new list(x, nullptr));
```

Comment: when use nullptr ,i got an error: [Error] 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Løt Fï use NULL then. Does your compiler not support C++11?

Comment: i tried the 2 solutions (NULL and new list) but seem that is not create a new box every iteration.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But If you use NULL, after each iteration, tab[i] will be a list* pointing to a list with info=10, suivant=NULL. And there will be 5 such instances in your vector when the loop finishes

Comment: And if you want tab[i] to be the head of a list with more valid nodes, you can call insert_beg(tab[i], Val) multiple time

Answer (score 0):

this is the 'insert_beg' function looklike:

```
void insert_beg(list* &debut,int x){
list* nouveau;
nouveau = new list;
nouveau->info = x;
nouveau->suivant = debut;
debut = nouveau;
}
```

Comment: I think it's part of the question.

Comment: So please delete this answer and edit your question with this new information.